# Update value of a key using batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have an app.config file in "C:\Users\abc\Test" location

```
<appSettings>   
    <add key="AdapterName" value="QAT" />
</appSettings>
```

Using batch scripting I want to change the value of key AdapterName to other value say from QAT to ABC
I tried doing but to no avail.

Comment: You can't replace text inline with batch. Consider powershell instead.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard : Any workaround?

Comment: yes, powershell. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/517760/how-to-search-and-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-cmd-or-powershell/517762) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Download [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript and store it in same directory as the batch file below.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF
if not exist "%UserProfile%\Test\app.config" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(key=\x22AdapterName\x22 value=\x22)[^\x22]*" "$1ABC" /XSEQ /F "%UserProfile%\Test\app.config" /O -
```

`\x22` is `"` specified in hexadecimal form as an argument string can't contain a double quote character.

The regular expression search string is:

```
(key="AdapterName" value=")[^"]*
```

The regular expression replace string back-references with `$1` the string found by the expression inside the round brackets which is here a fixed string to keep that part of found string unmodified and replace the string found by `[^"]*` matching all characters except a double quote zero or more times by the string `ABC`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`